# react.js antd modal wrong behaviour

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, modal-dialog, antd

So I have this big messy component, I will try to slim it down, however keep most of it since I am unsure at this point what could be cause.

The issue is, that the game works as expected. When it is time for the modal to render, it appears at the bottom left of the page, with no styling floating left. The functionality however works as expected, the buttons work and it displays the raw content.

```
import { Modal } from 'antd';
//rest of imports

const initialState = {
  visible: false,
  streak: 0,
  score: 0,
  turn: 0,
  previousPicks: [],
  result: { result: "", player: "", computer: "" }
};

class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.turnLimit = 10;
    this.state = initialState;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.setState(initialState)
  }

  updateScore = () => {
    //handles score
  }

  updatePreviousPicks = () => {
    //update game data
  }

  onClickHandler = async (choice) => {
    //fetching data from backend 
          self.showModal();
  }

  getAIResult = () => {
    //
  }

  showModal = () => {
    if (this.state.turn === 10) {
      this.setState({
        visible: true,
      });
    }
  }

  handleOk = () => {
    this.setState(initialState)
  }

  handleCancel = () => {
    this.setState(initialState)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>


        <Modal
          title="Basic Modal"
          centered={true}
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onOk={this.handleOk}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}></Modal>


          </div>
        <div className="container">
          <div id="rockDiv" className={`choice`} onClick={() => this.onClickHandler("rock")}>
            <Choices choice="rock"></Choices>
          </div>
          <div id="paperDiv" className={`choice`} onClick={() => this.onClickHandler("paper")}>
            <Choices choice="paper"></Choices>
          </div>
          <div id="scissorsDiv" className={`choice`} onClick={() => this.onClickHandler("scissors")}>
            <Choices choice="scissors"></Choices>
          </div>
          <Score score={this.state.score} bonus={this.state.streak} turn={this.state.turn} />
          <div id="PlayerResult" className={this.state.result.result}  >
            {this.state.turn >= 1 ? <p>You</p> : <p></p>}
            <Answer choice={`${this.state.result.player}`} />
          </div>
          <div id="AIResult" className={this.getAIResult()} >
            {this.state.turn >= 1 ? <p>AI</p> : <p></p>}
            <Answer choice={`${this.state.result.computer}`} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Game
```

I have tried removing all CSS from the component, and still the modal does not show with the default antd design?

Comment: which modal library you're using ?

Comment: @TungDuong I use antd, I have included it in the code now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand that current style you have doesn't like example of Antd.
Missing is you didn't import styles of Antd like this.

```
import { Modal, Button } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
```

Just need import style you will have what you need.
You can check my example here https://codesandbox.io/embed/8lr93mw8yj

Answer (score -1):

```
<Modal
          title="Basic Modal"
          centered="true"
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onOk={this.handleOk}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}></Modal>
```

You do not need to wrap the `"true"` in brackets here as you are not calling a variable.